# Eigen: Initializing Matrix to Identity does not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen

I have a template class `B` that derives from a template class `A`. 
Class `A` has 3 template parameters (the follow is `A.h`):

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER

#include "Eigen/Dense"

template<typename T = double, int xsize = Eigen::Dynamic, int ysize = Eigen::Dynamic>
class A {

public:
    // Constructor, etc.
    ...
```

which we derive from in class `B`:

```
#ifndef B_HEADER
#define B_HEADER

#include "A.h"
#include "Eigen/Dense"

template<typename T= double, int ysize = Eigen::Dynamic>
class B : public A<T, 4, ysize> {
private:

    Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4> Hj = Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4>::Identity(2, 4);

public:
    // Constructor, etc.
    ...
```

Then in the main function, I instantiate `B` like this:

```
 B<float> b(...
```

which I expect to pick up the template defaults. When I try to compile this in Cygwin G++, I don't get any compile errors. However, with Ubuntu G++, I am getting the errors

```
/mnt/c/Dropbox/drive/kf/src/b.h:11:68: error: declaration of ‘Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4> B<T, ysize>::ysize’
     Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4> Hj = Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4>::Identity(2, 4);
                                                      ^
/mnt/c/Dropbox/drive/kf/src/b.h:7:38: error:  shadows template parm ‘int ysize’
 template<typename T = double, int ysize = -1>
                               ^
/mnt/c/Dropbox/drive/kf/src/b.h:11:75: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
     Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4> Hj = Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4>::Identity(2, 4);
                                                             ^
/mnt/c/Dropbox/drive/kf/src/b.h:11:58: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 3)
     Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4> Hj = Eigen::Matrix<T, ysize, 4>::Identity(2, 4);
                                                   ^
```

What is the issue with this pattern?

Note: It doesn't hurt me one bit to move the initialization to the constructor. I just don't understand why the Cygwin G++ compiler is fine with this, but the Ubuntu version isn't.

EDIT: Compiler info obtained from `g++ --version`

```
Windows Cygwin G++ : g++ (GCC) 6.4.0
Ubuntu G++         : g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: What are the respective versions of g++ (`g++ --version`)?

Comment: Maybe an issue in GCC 5.4 that has been fixed in 6.4?

Comment: Did you try compiling with `-std=c++11` with g++5.4? This is activated by default starting from g++6.1